# C / determining content of received UDP packet

Tags: c, udp

When receiving a UDP packet, where I do not know neither content nor structure, how can I find out what the content is? Is that possible somehow? Wireshark tells me the data is:
`12:03:01:00:00:00:00:00:1f:44:fe:a2:07:e2:4c:28:00:15:e1:e0:00:80:12:61`

The question is just about the data itself, not header of lower layers.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have a bunch of bytes. It could be any number of structured data items.

Comment: If you intercept the beginning of an UDP transmission and it starts with a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) you can interpret the package according to that number. However (as Yann stated) you will often end up with a bunch of bytes that could easily be another "lol" chat message.

Comment: I see. In that case it is not possible, thanks so far. It is an user-defined packet structure, so I guess no way to find out. Except ask the one who specified it.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark shows UDP header. There is 2 port numbers. Usually another port number is reserved for the used protocol (not always). 
You may look from [the port reservation table](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt) which is the used protocol.

And if you are lucky, you find the protocol specification from Web and you can open the content of the packet.

Comment: thanks for answering, please take a look at my comment above.